# Как исправить ошибку в java - Connection faild: ecconrefused

Tags: java, android, c#, android-studio, wcf

Делаю Android-приложение, которое будет получать json-строку, парсить её и 
выводить данные из неё. Сама строка создается в WCF-службе.

Если в качестве URL-адреса, откуда читать строку, указать на этот файл, лежащий на хостинге - все в порядке, файл читается. Но, если я запускаю службу, и указываю в андроиде в качестве url - адрес на этот файл, размещенный на localhost с помощью Visual Studio, возникает ошибка:
[image: Ошибка]

Как её исправить, чтобы андроид считывал эту строку с localhost-адреса?

Answer (score 5):

`localhost` - это ссылка на себя. То есть, если вы заходите с телефона на `localhost` - это будет ссылка на сам телефон. Если с компьютера - это ссылка на компьютер. Вам надо указывать реальный IP-аддрес, а не `localhost`

Comment: Даже если я работаю с эмулятором в Android Studio, нужно указывать реальный IP?

Comment: @Icnw  В любом случае `localhost` - это ссылка на себя. В случае с эмулятором это ссылка на эмулятор. Сейчас посмотрю, как определить, какой IP надо указывать для эмулятора

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses
IP-адресс хостовой машины (компьютера - `10.0.2.2`)

Comment: а где этот IP-шник надо прописать?

Comment: @lcnw вместо `localhost`

Comment: Соединение идет, но json-файл не находится - `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:25734/Test.svc/json/GetDataTable`.

Comment: @lcnw А эмулятор вообще стандартный?

Comment: @lcnw, я только что проверил, все правильно, у меня работает так. Проверьте, доступен ли ваш файл с самого компьютера через localhost.

Comment: @metalurgus, запускаю службу в VS, перехожу по ссылке с localhost - файл скачивается, все нормально. Открываю ссылку в браузере - все нормально, отображается вся строка. А в Android Studio ругается, мол файла нет. Эмулятор "родной", "студийный"

Comment: @Incw, может у вас какой файрвол чего-то блокирует?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет, ничего такого

Comment: попробуйте проверить доступность этого файла по сети с любого другого устройства